# ¿Es correcta esta implementación del patrón strategy en java?

Tags: java

Leyendo un artículo de Microsoft, trato de implementar el patrón **strategy** en un proyecto propio, la idea es la siguiente: Tengo un JTextArea y un botón de imprimir y un `JComboBox` que permite seleccionar el formato de impresión pdf/txt/csv, el código funciona (aunque falta implementar el código que de verdad genera los formatos correctos, pero eso lo haré después.) Pero no sé si estoy implementado realmente el patrón **strategy** o solo estoy haciendo una copia barata de él. Aquí código.

```
public interface Impresora {

public void print(); }
```

y las siguientes clases que implementan la `interface`

```
public class ImprimePDF implements Impresora{

private String documento;

public ImprimePDF(String doc){
    documento = doc;
}

public void print(){
    System.out.println("¡esto es un pdf wow!");
    System.out.println(documento);
}}
```

y para csv

```
public class ImprimeCSV implements Impresora{

private String documento;

public ImprimeCSV(String doc){
    documento = doc;
}

public void print(){
    System.out.println("¡Esto es un csv, wow!");
    System.out.println(documento);
}}
```

El código para txt es similar.
Mi vista es la siguiente:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Vista{

private JTextArea area;
private JFrame ventana;
private JButton imprimir;
private JLabel label;
private JComboBox box;

public Vista(){

    ventana = new JFrame();
    ventana.setTitle("Line of fire");
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ventana.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    area = new JTextArea(10,35);                
    JPanel panelcontrol = new JPanel();
    label    = new JLabel("Seleccione el formato:");
    box      = new JComboBox(new String[]{"txt", "pdf", "csv"});
    imprimir = new JButton(new ImageIcon("printer.png"));
    imprimir.addActionListener(new Printer(this));

    panelcontrol.add(label);
    panelcontrol.add(box);
    panelcontrol.add(imprimir);

    ventana.add(new JScrollPane(area), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    ventana.add(panelcontrol, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    ventana.pack();
    ventana.setVisible(true);
}

public JTextArea getTextArea(){
    return area;
}

public JComboBox getComboBox(){
    return box;
}}
```

Y por último mi clase contexto (que también funciona como la clase Listener), que según entiendo, es la que decide qué implementación particular del algoritmo instanciar es:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Printer implements ActionListener{

//Para obtener el tipo de impresión correcta
private JComboBox combobox;
private JTextArea area;    
private Impresora default_printer;

public Printer(Vista vayjay){

    combobox = vayjay.getComboBox();
    area     = vayjay.getTextArea();            
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String tipoimpresion = combobox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String document = area.getText();
    switch(tipoimpresion){
        case "txt" : 
            default_printer = new ImprimeTXT(document);                
            break;
        case "pdf" :
            default_printer = new ImprimePDF(document);                
            break;
        case "csv" :
            default_printer = new ImprimeCSV(document);                
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("su trabajo se está procesando...");
    default_printer.print();
    System.out.println("Trabajo terminado.");
}}
```

Si me pueden indicar qué estoy haciendo mal, se los agradeceré mucho, es que los case del switch me parecen súper sospechosos, según leí, este patrón **strategy** es precisamente para no tener `switch-case`.

Comment: Probablemente esto no es una pregunta ideal para SO, porque deja mucho espacio para opinar. Pero para que no sales sin nada, revisa ejemplos del `strategy pattern` y te vas a dar cuenta que tipicamente el objeto en cuestion lleva su estrategia adentro, y que el contexto puede cambiar la estrategia que se aplica. Eso también acabaría con el switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No tienes nada malo en el código,  el *patrón strategy* está bien implementado, la razón del *switch-case* es porque el *listener*, es el encargado de crear las impresoras, es decir que *el listener* se convierte en una factoría de objetos concretos, que implementan *la estrategia* , La naturaleza de la factoría consiste en bifurcar y determinar el *objeto X* a crear, así que es normal ver el *switch-case*

*Printer.java* tiene dos responsabilidades, ambas responsabilidades están en ***actionPermorfed***

si suponemos un método llamado ***actualizarImpresora*** que se encargue de cambiar, escoger la impresora a utilizar (el valor de *default_printer*) y actualizar el documento entonces el código se reduce en :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    System.out.println("su trabajo se está procesando...");
    actualizarImpresora(); 
    default_printer.print();    
    System.out.println("Trabajo terminado.");
}}
```

ésta es una solución parcial, puesto que *actionPerformed* no debería actualizar nada, eso debería hacerlo el propio *comboBox* a través de un *ItemListener*

**Una mejor Solución  :**

Primero que nada, hay que modificar la interfaz Impresora, para que permita cambiar el documento en la marcha, después de todo, una impresora imprime varios documentos, si fuesen desechables, tendríamos que comprar una impresora por documento (imagina costearlo...)

```
public interface Impresora {
    public void print(); 
    public void setDocument(Object document); // permite cambiar el documento "on the fly"
}
```

Luego a la clase *Printer*, se le crea impresoras por defecto, que coincidan con el índice del combobox.

Archivo ***Printer.java***

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Printer implements ActionListener{

//Para obtener el tipo de impresión correcta
private JComboBox combobox;
private JTextArea area;    
private Impresora default_printer;
private Impresora[] impresoras;

public Printer(Vista vayjay){

    impresoras = new Impresora[]{
        new ImprimeTXT(),
        new ImprimePDF(),
        new ImprimeCSV()
    };
    combobox = vayjay.getComboBox();
    combobox.addItemListener(new ItemListener{
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
            default_printer = impresoras[combobox.getSelectedIndex()];        
        }
    })
    area     = vayjay.getTextArea();
    default_printer = impresoras[0];
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    System.out.println("su trabajo se está procesando...");
    default_printer.setDocument(area.getText())       
    default_printer.print();
    System.out.println("Trabajo terminado.");
}}
```

Lo que hace ahora el archivo Printer.java, es que le añade un *ItemListener* al *comboBox* el cuál es el encargado de cambiar la impresora a utilizar cuando el usuario seleccione una opción.

Ahora *actionPerformed* sólo actualiza el documento en la impresora, e imprime, no necesita hacer nada más.

Comment: Tu aporte me ayudó demasiado, gracias.